# Generar archivo Excel con php

Tags: php, html, jquery, phpexcel

Necesito generar un archivo Excel con php, pero no se como hacerlo, alguien me puede ayudar con esto, estoy trabajando con 000webhost con una cuenta gratuita, si alguien sabe como hacerlo les agradeceria.

Comment: Dudo mucho que nadie te responda como quieres. Preguntas tan amplias suelen ser demasiado extensas de responder con acierto. Primero investiga un poco y si tienes dudas, pregunta el problema donde te atascaste. Para empezar puedes hacer [una búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+generar+excel) en este mismo sitio y verás opciones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo lo habia hecho de una manera simple y sin librerias

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=usersList.xls');
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nombres</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
    <th>Ciudad</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>00043</td>
    <td>Juan</td>
    <td>Pepe</td>
    <td>1544552115</td>
    <td>Caracas</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Se puede usar un bucle que liste los datos que sean necesario desde la base de datos, pero eso va a depender de ti.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es bastante amplia.
Si lo que quieres es generar un excel a partir de una tabla html ya cargada lo que puedes hacer es usar jquery datatable que ya trae nativa esa funcionalidad. No solo Excel, sino PDF y CSV.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Si es eso, tendrías que explicitar un poco mas la pregunta.

Comment: Eduardo lo que quiero es algo asi: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319624/aplicar-formatos-con-phpexcel/319626?noredirect=1#comment580677_319626