# Aplicar formatos con PHPExcel

Tags: php, php7, phpexcel

Estoy tratando de sacar un reporte con PHPExcel, pero no logro lo que quiero, quiero conseguir algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que consigo es los siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado en internet como ponerle ese formato hago tal cual como lo he visto pero resulta que al momento de generar el archivo ahi algo mal escrito que no me deja generarlo.
Y este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
<?php
  require ('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
  include ('index.php');
  // Crea un nuevo objeto PHPExcel
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  // Agregar Informacion
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
     ->setCellValue('A1', 'Placa');
  for($i=1;$i<=date("d",time());$i++){
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,1, $i."/".date("m")."/".date("Y"));
 }
 $sql= mysqli_query($conex,"SELECT fecha, placa FROM asistencia, vehiculouser WHERE asistencia.idvehuser = vehiculouser.idvehuser AND LEFT(fecha,2) = SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE,6,2)");
$i=0;
$k=0;
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if($fecha[$i-$k] != $fila['placa']){
        $fecha[$i]=$fila['placa'];
        $placas = $placas +1;
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    $fecha[$i] = date("d",strtotime($fila['fecha']));
    $i=$i+1;
    $k=$i;
}
$i=0;
$y=2;
while($i<=sizeof($fecha)-1){
    if(strlen($fecha[$i])===6){
        $placa = $fecha[$i];
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$y,$placa);
        /*$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setRowHeight(60);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($i,1);*/
        $y = $y + 1;
        $i = $i + 1;
    } else {
        for($j=1;$j<=date("d",time());$j++){
            if($fecha[$i] == $j ){
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$y-1,'1');
                $i = $i + 1; 
            } else {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i,$y-1,'F');
            }
        }
    }
}
// Renombrar Hoja
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('ENERO.');
// Establecer la hoja activa, para que cuando se abra el documento se muestre primero.
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Se modifican los encabezados del HTTP para indicar que se envía un archivo de Excel.
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Asistencia Vehicular .xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit; ?>
```

por cierto uso la libreria PHPExcel

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar Lo siguiente para darle el formato que quieras a tu Excel:

```js
//Color
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A2')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('0000ff');
//Alto
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);
//Ancho
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(100);
//Negrita
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Te he puesto un rango de celdas en el //Color para que veas que puedes poner una sola celda, o un rango de celdas, para trabajar más rápido. Espero que te sirva :D

Comment: Hola Fergush, tengo una duda, yo puedo usarlo de la siguiente manera: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(40);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($i)->setWidth(100);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($i,1)->getFont()->setBold(true);???

Comment: Si no me equivoco, tu segundo getStyle($i,1) no es correcto, ya que deben ser coordenadas concretas: getStyle("A1","B2"), por ejemplo