# Al descargar y abrir un archivo hecho con PHPExcel, este contiene caracteres ilegibles

Tags: php, phpexcel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es lo que me arroja cuando intento descargar el excel.

Ya he usado ob_end_clean();
pero sigo con el mismo problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo una función muy simple solo coloco un logo y titulo a mi hoja de trabajo.

Y también he intentado usar una plantilla pero pasa lo mismo.

Comment: [PHPExcel es una librería obsoleta hace mucho tiempo, desde 2015... 7 años es mucho en informática...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128583/29967). Considera usar PHPSpreadSheet en su lugar.

Comment: Acá hay [una respuesta que puede ser útil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/319422/40877). Utiliza `headers` en lugar de librerías externas. Respecto al error, no se si estás usando asincronismo (`ajax` por ejemplo). De ser así descártalo de una vez porque no funciona.

Comment: Si estoy usando Ajax para llamar a la función.
¿En todo caso si quiero usar ajax como lo aria o la forma de poder usarlo?

Comment: Información de la etiqueta [phpexcel]: _PHPExcel ha sido descontinuada, los creadores recomiendan no usarla más y migrar a PHPSpreadsheet_. Por cierto, el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quien tenga el mismo problema que yo.
El problema es el ajax.
Y encontré un post donde lo resolvió de una manera magistral.
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/phpexcel-con-ajax-1133271/

Que alivio cuando encontré esta respuesta.

No entendía el pq del problema asta que leí lo que comento
DjCrazy.

Comment: _Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia. Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia._ Pon en tu respuesta lo que ha resuelto tu duda. Ponte a pensar en lo siguiente: un usuario llega a tener un problema similar, encuentra tu respuesta, pulsa en el enlace y... ¡error 404! Es por ello que la respuesta _completa_ debe estar aquí. Luego, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.